# How to fix "nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed" in Nginx with Django?

Tags: python, django, nginx

I want to use Django, Python, Nginx.

I made the /etc/nginx/sites-availabe/microdomains.conf file like this:

```
upstream django {
  server unix:///home/christian/microdomains/microdomains.sock;
}

server {
  listen   80;
  server_name ubuntuchristian;
  charset   utf-8;

  # max upload size
  client_max_body_size 75M;

  # Django media and static files
  location /media {
    alias /home/christian/microdomains/media;
  }
  location /static {
    alias /home/christian/microdomains/static;
  }

  # Send all non-media requests to the Django server.
  location / {
    uwsgi_pass django;
    include   /home/christian/microdomains/uwsgi_params;
  }
}
```

However, when testing, it generates the error:
(md) christian@ubuntuchristian:~/microdomains$ sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-available/microdomains.conf
nginx: [emerg] "upstream" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-available/microdomains.conf:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-available/microdomains.conf test failed

Any suggestions to handle this error?

I need that the nginx works fine.